# Implement billing email reminders

Tags: node.js, web, sendgrid

I would like to implement automatic email notification system for recurring billing in Nodejs. E.g. when subscription is about to expire in 5 days or in 24 hours I want to send an email reminder for a user.

I am using Sendgrid as mailing service. Sending an email is a easy task. Question is what is the best practice for implementing such workflow.

I imagine that cronjob could be setup to run every hour or so.
Script is executed that finds all the users with subscriptions which expires in 5 days or 24 hours. Doing so would lead to sending notification every time cronjob is run. I have to track which users are notified already to avoid duplicated emails.

Comment: No need to run it every 2 hours, run it daily on 00:01.

Comment: I just want to make sure that if something goes wrong e.g. network error. I wouldn't have to wait another day to retry.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a cron job for that, like I said in comment, daily. After you find and sent emails you can check sendgrid api to make sure email has been delivered.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/deliveries.html

You can also make a web hook to check that

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html

the rest of implementation in logic.